# SQL Server - Return multiple row values in single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got this table which has email address of 3 employees in SQL Server

Table structure is

```
EmployeeId, EmployeeName, Employee email address
```

Data is like this:

```
1   Conrad   Conrad@test.com
```

Output I need is the e-mail addresses in a single row / one column:

```
conrad@test.com; ali@test.com; will@test.com
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005) might be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b50f8/1)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
(SELECT ';' + e.EmailAddress
FROM Employee e
FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000) AS CSV
```

From SQL Server 2005 upward. [See more here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/25/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column/)

Answer (score 1):

`FOR XML PATH()` is good solution for SQL Server:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT 'x@example.com' AS mail
    UNION
    SELECT 'y@example.com'
    UNION
    SELECT 'z@example.com'
)
SELECT
    STUFF((SELECT
        mail + ','
    FROM
        x
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Query above returns `@example.com,y@example.com,z@example.com,`.

In your case query would look like (could contain errors):

```
SELECT
  EmployeeId, 
  EmployeeName, 
  (SELECT
        STUFF((SELECT
            [e.email address] + ','
        FROM
            employees e
        WHERE
                e.EmployeeId = EmployeeId
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')) AS mails
   FROM
     employees
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `COALESCE`

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)

select @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',','') + Employee_email_address from table1 where EmployeeId = @EmployeeId
select @listStr
```

Query above will return @example.com,y@example.com,z@example.com,

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor for that.

```
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(256) 
DECLARE @EmailCollection VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT Email 
FROM tableName

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @email   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   

       SET  @EmailCollection = @EmailCollection + @email + ';'
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @email   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

And at the end you can return @EmailCollection